# Python pandas how to receive signals from a constantly replenished csv file?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a csv file that is constantly being updated-appended:

Let's call it signal.csv

It has 3 columns Answers, Score and step and it looks like this in general

| Answers | Score | step |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 0 | 2 | 0 |
| 0 | 3 | 2 |
| -1 | 1 | 0 |
| 0 | 2 | 0 |
| 0 | 3 | -2 |
| 0 | 4 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 0 | 2 | 0 |
| 0 | 3 | 2 |

Answer shows by unit (1,-1) the direction of the graph(Up, Down)

Score shows how many tick lines the graph went either down or up

Step shows the number that I pass to the class function and matches it against the same number in the score column, observing the direction of the graph (2, -2)

Here, for clarity, I betray the number 3

I want to somehow receive these signals and transfer them to another csv file in which there will always be one line with this signal

That is, if there is a -1 value in signal.csv in the last row and Answers column that arrived, then it will be written to out.csv

When signal 3 arrives in the last row of the Step column, it will be written in out.csv

Expected result:

1)There was no signal

|  |
| --- |
| 0 |

2)The signal from the Answer column that cleans and overwrites out.csv

|  |
| --- |
| -1 |

3)The signal from the Step column, which also cleans and overwrites out.csv

|  |
| --- |
| -2 |

In general, this is something like checking the Answer and Step columns and their last line - if something other than zeros appears, it is written to out.csv

Comment: please provide the explicit expected output

Comment: I have clarified the expected result!

Comment: OK, still not clear to me but many someone else will have more luck ;)

Comment: I will try to explain in words! In general, this is something like checking the Answer and Step columns and their last line - if something other than zeros appears, it is written to out.csv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to check if by csv file and take only the last value

```
 def Signal():
    df = pd.read_csv('YouCsv', usecols=['Answers','step','Score' ])
    df = df.tail(1)
    if df.step.item() > 0:
        a = pd.DataFrame({(df.step.item())})
        a.to_csv('YouSignal.csv', index=False, header=False)
    elif df.step.item() < 0:
        a = pd.DataFrame({(df.step.item())})
        a.to_csv('YouSignal.csv', index=False, header=False)
    elif df.Answers.item() > 0:
        a = pd.DataFrame({(df.Answers.item())})
        a.to_csv('YouSignal.csv', index=False, header=False)
    elif df.Answers.item() < 0:
        a = pd.DataFrame({(df.Answers.item())})
        a.to_csv('YouSignal.csv', index=False, header=False)
    else:
        a = pd.DataFrame({((0))})
        a.to_csv('YouSignal.csv', index=False, header=False)
```